# Vue-style-loader extract css in separate file

Tags: webpack, vue.js

I would like to ask if how can I include the css of the third party library that I install. I use vue-strap so inside the node_modules are the component files with .vue extension. My problem now is when I do the `npm run build` for my production build the css inside the .vue files in node_modules are not extracted in a css file but injected in the `head` like this `<style type="text/css">` Here are the gist link of my config:

**webpack.prod.conf.js**
https://gist.github.com/webdevsyd/c5e9b1597cfd4c7e13e9983e8f6f27ab

**utils.js**
https://gist.github.com/webdevsyd/e625300a5d80afa9e9aa36304175240a

**webpack.base.conf.js**
https://gist.github.com/webdevsyd/b907fbad1317c3e90c059f828620fd68

Comment: hi @SydneyLoteria did you find any solution i'm running into the same issue